# How to mirror a sprite in PIXI.js

Tags: mirroring, pixi.js

I need to flip a sprite by its bottom line. I know theres a way to flip it by a `scale` property. But that would be only a flip my its center. Searching the Pixi.js documentation wasn't helpful either.

Answer (score 16):

I have no experience with Pixi, but from what I've read, you have to set the [anchor](http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Sprite.html#anchor) property of your sprite to the bottom of the sprite, then [scale](http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Sprite.html#scale) by -1. Something like this; please note I didn't test it.

```
mySprite.anchor.y = 1;     /* 0 = top, 0.5 = center, 1 = bottom */
mySprite.scale.y *= -1;    /* flip vertically */
```

Comment: Ill try that if theres hopefully a anchor property

Comment: There's no reason to set the anchor to flip the sprite. It's sufficient to negatively scale the axis you wan't to invert :)
`mySprite.scale.y = -1`
would be enough

Comment: @KristofferDorph Thanks for commenting, as it made me aware the PixiJS documentation hyperlinks needed an update. Might be my code sample needs an update too; I didn't test it with the latest version of PixiJS. Anyway, the anchor determines which pixels hold their position as the sprite is flipped. And that is exactly what OP's question was all about: to mirror a sprite around its bottom line, not around its center. So I'd say it matters.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right about that. Did not read his question all the way through. You're right :)